# Can someone point good samples / examples on Custom Dataflow Component (Transformation) + SSIS

Tags: ssis

Can anyone point out some good samples / examples on Custom Dataflow Component (Transformation) other than one on codeplex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, MS has a really good hands on training document on this particular topic: [Custom DF Component](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1C2A7DD2-3EC3-4641-9407-A5A337BEA7D3&displaylang=en)